# ImportError: Version check of the existing lazylinker compiled file. Looking for version 0.211, but found None

Tags: theano

```
C:\Users\meela\Anaconda3\python.exe E:/TTIGAN/test.py

You can find the C code in this temporary file: C:\Users\meela\AppData\Local\Temp\theano_compilation_error_zncbj7_k
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\meela\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 81, in <module>
    actual_version, force_compile, _need_reload))

ImportError: Version check of the existing lazylinker compiled file. Looking for version 0.211, but found None. Extra debug information: force_compile=False, _need_reload=True

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\meela\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 105, in <module>
    actual_version, force_compile, _need_reload))

ImportError: Version check of the existing lazylinker compiled file. Looking for version 0.211, but found None. Extra debug information: force_compile=False, _need_reload=True

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/TTIGAN/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import skipthoughts

  File "E:\TTIGAN\skipthoughts.py", line 6, in <module>
    import theano

  File "C:\Users\meela\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\__init__.py", line 110, in <module>

    from theano.compile import (

  File "C:\Users\meela\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>

    from theano.compile.mode import *

  File "C:\Users\meela\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\mode.py", line 11, in <module>

    import theano.gof.vm

  File "C:\Users\meela\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\vm.py", line 674, in <module>

    from . import lazylinker_c

  File "C:\Users\meela\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 140, in <module>

    preargs=args)

  File "C:\Users\meela\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 2388, in compile_str

    (status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. ')))
. 

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem, got me 2 days to resolve!
It was from path environment, i had another mingw path imported in variables and i removed it!

Comment: I removed C:\MinGW\Bin from the path and restart PyCharm, and it works well.

Answer (score 24):

Same problem here, solved by installing  a mingw-w64 import library for python(on Windows via conda) in your CLI type:

```
conda install -c anaconda libpython
```

Comment: This one should have been selected as the answer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my Mac. Installing theano via pip should fix this issue.

`pip install theano`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it was caused by an old version of anaconda from 2014 that I forgot I even had.   Just renaming the old directory fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The solution that worked for me was to uninstall my MinGW gcc compiler and reinstall the latest [one.](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tdm-gcc/) Make sure to restart your CLI before testing it.